# Подключаем файлы языков

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как подключить к своему приложению файл *.res в Delphi 7?

Целью является "предоставить пользователю выбор языка в интерфейсе программы".

Comment: А чем вам INI файлы в данном случае не подходят?

Comment: тем что у меня их нету,а есть набор *.res файлов)

Comment: кому может пригодится вот что-то похожее,но здесь только курсоры и изображения..

http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/load_image_cursor_from_res.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишите пожалуйста явно, какая именно схема локализации используется.

Если хотите использовать схему, предлагаемую VCL и добавить к ней возможность переключения языков:

Прочтите [этот топик](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dynamic_Switching_of_Resource_DLLs) или его аналог из хелпа D7 (последний полнее), текст ссылается на пример RichEdit и конкретно [этот модуль](http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/radstudiodemos/trunk/Delphi/VCL/RichEdit/reinit.pas?view=markup), который собственно и реализует повторную загрузку *Resource DLL*.

Answer (score 1):

1. подключение ресурса: `{$R resources.res}`
2. в дельфи есть встроенная фича поддержки интернациональности. Не помню как она называется, но переводы получаются в dll